# How can get text from XfxEntry?

Tags: xamarin, c#-4.0, xamarin.forms

I have used Xamrin with vs 2017 professional. 
I want to use a floating text view in the cross-platform application.

I have used below link but it not describe how can get a text from it.

[link] https://github.com/XamFormsExtended/Xfx.Controls

Main.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:xfx="clr-namespace:Xfx;assembly=Xfx.Controls"
             x:Class="Reports_Rpt.Signup">
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" Spacing="10" BackgroundColor="#4B8CA8">
            <Image Source="iconXamagon.png">
            </Image>

        </StackLayout>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="2,2,2,2" BackgroundColor="White">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <xfx:XfxEntry 

                          Placeholder="Enter your name"
                          Text="{Binding Name}"
                          ErrorText="{Binding NameErrorText}" />
            </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: It looks like you are using data binding, so the text should be in the `Name` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have bound the Text property to Name, so the Name property of your model should contain the text.

Alternatively, you can assign a name to the control and reference it that way

```
<xfx:XfxEntry x:Name="myEntry" Placeholder="Enter your name"
              Text="{Binding Name}" 
              ErrorText="{Binding NameErrorText}" />
```

then in your code-behind

```
var value = myEntry.Text;
```